# How to define empty in D?

Tags: d

In C you can do empty defines but how do you do this in D?

```
#define MYAPI
MYAPI int printThis(const char *str);
```

How can I do this in D?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't.

The real question to ask is what is that macro trying to accomplish in the first place? Often that pattern in C is better represented by `extern(System)` in D - indicating that it is linked according to the current operating system's conventions. In C and C++, you use a macro that can be defined to `extern "C"` or some `__declspec` to account to different OS, compiler, and language (remember, C and C++ aren't the same thing, though they can share code) combinations. But in D, it is standardized to `extern(System)`.

So again, the answer is you don't do exactly that, but the higher level goal you are going for may be achieved in different ways, so it depends.

Answer (score 1):

```
extern (D) int printThis(string str);
```

This promises that the function is defined elsewhere and will be linked in. It's not the same as a forward declaration in C; you don't need it to call a function earlier in a file than its body, for instance.

You can also use `extern (C)` and `extern (C++)`.

You might also look into [D interface files](https://dlang.org/dmd-windows.html#interface-files), which the compiler generates from your source code and only include what the compiler thinks it'll need to compile something against that code.